# Multithreading printing with python

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, logging

I am attempting to use Selenium to automate websites while using multithreading.

Currently I have ran into issues trying to print out logging info through the code inside the test case code.

This is a snippet of the code im working with.

**Test Case Code -**

```
def test_logic():

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'./chromedriver')
    url = 'https://discordapp.com/channels/'
    driver.get(url)


    print(datetime.now(),'Discord Launched, Searching For Fields.')
    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='email']")
    inputElement.send_keys('coding@yahoo.com')
    print(datetime.now(),'Typing in email bar')

    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='password']")
    inputElement.send_keys('ilove2code')
    print(datetime.now(),'Typing in password bar')



    time.sleep(20)
    driver.quit()
```

**Multithreading Code -**

```
def multi():

    N = 2   # Number of browsers to spawn
    thread_list = list()

    # Start test
    for i in range(N):
        t = threading.Thread(name='Task {}'.format(i), target=test_logic)
        t.start()
        time.sleep(1)
        print (t.name , 'started!')
        thread_list.append(t)

    # Wait for all thre<ads to complete
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()

    print ('Test completed!')
```

Currently this is output that I have -

```
Task 0 started!
Task 1 started!
2019-09-03 10:50:37.914244 Discord Launched, Searching For Fields.
2019-09-03 10:50:38.248029 Discord Launched, Searching For Fields
2019-09-03 10:50:38.418392 Typing in email bar
2019-09-03 10:50:38.569400 Typing in password bar
2019-09-03 10:50:38.833535 Typing in email bar
2019-09-03 10:50:38.939082 Typing in password bar

Test completed!
```

and I am trying to achieve this output

```
Task 0 started!
Task 1 started!
2019-09-03 10:50:37.914244 Task 0 Discord Launched, Searching For Fields.
2019-09-03 10:50:38.248029 Task 1 Discord Launched, Searching For Fields
2019-09-03 10:50:38.418392 Task 0 Typing in email bar
2019-09-03 10:50:38.569400 Task 0 Typing in password bar
2019-09-03 10:50:38.833535 Task 1 Typing in email bar
2019-09-03 10:50:38.939082 Task 1 Typing in password bar

Test completed!
```

Any help and suggestions will gladly be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function `test_logic`, you can use the following functions:

```
t = threading.current_thread()
print(datetime.now(), t.name, 'Typing in password bar')
```

The [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) covers the explanation and the other functions that you can use. The `current_thread` helps fetch the `Thread` object. Then you can use the attribute `name` to get the identifier you require.